# Unable to Handle js date - Moment

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

```
moment('Sat Sep 12 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)').format()
// Error: core-test.js:52920 Uncaught Error: input not handled by moment(…)
```

I am miffed as to why moment cannot handle this date, even when stripping it down I still can't get it to work it out.

```
var date = 'Sat Sep 12 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)'.split(' GMT')[0];
moment(date).format()
//The same error
```

Comment: can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: From the outset though it looks like the format you're using for the input into the moment function isn't allowed. http://momentjs.com/ - will show you what's allowed on the top. That's my initial impression.

Comment: I just tried your first example with moment 2.10.6 and it has a Deprecation warning but works, your second example also works and without the Deprecation warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide `moment` a format to use to parse your string: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

But your date format isn't possible with the options available so you have to strip out some of the information.  Namely the reference the timezone name for the offset "GMT" and the "GMT Daylight Time".  Since the timezone is encoded in the "+0100" part I'm going to assume that it's fine to remove those references.

First create a function to "clean" the string date:

```
function cleanDateString(formattedDate) {
  return formattedDate.replace(/(.*?)(\w{3})(((\+|-)\d{4}).*)/g,"$1$4");
}
```

If you invoke the function on the string you provided `cleanDateString('Sat Sep 12 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)')` the output will be

> "Sat Sep 12 2015 15:00:00 +0100"

Now this is something that can be parsed by moment using the right format.

If you look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ then the format that you would need for this string is

> 'ddd MMM DD YYYY mm:hh:ss ZZ'

If you combine the two things from above, then you can get your date like this

```
function parseCustomDate(formattedDate) {
  return moment(cleanDateString(formattedDate),'ddd MMM DD YYYY mm:hh:ss ZZ');
}
```

And that will work with your given string

```
parseCustomDate('Sat Sep 12 2015 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)')
```

---

#### Note on the Regex

If you want details on how exactly the regex works, you can look at the "Explanation" and the "Match Information" sections at this link: https://regex101.com/r/tH6hM9/1.  I used that to tweak the groupings and the rules

Answer (score -1):

Your Date Format should look like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
var date2 = '2015-09-12T15:00:00+00:00'; // UTC
```

Comment: Not sure why somebody has down voted that without an explanation.